# Listening all upstart jobs and events by python

Tags: message-queue, dbus, upstart

I want to listen all Upstart jobs/events on a Linux host (Amazon EC2 Linux AMI) by Python, in order to bridge all jobs/events to a RabbitMQ server, so that a worker host can record it and do something at some jobs/events.

The version of Upstart is 0.6.5.

I found "dbus-python" module (already installed in system). but I can not understand it.

How can I do that ?